# RDLC Column Data Not Showing

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I'm creating a report in VS2010; I'm using a table with grouping, and have assigned the datasource, which is a stored procedure from SQL server 2008 R2.  Every other report I've done is fine; this one is giving me fits.

I have 4 columns that hold a decimal valued item (`ROWNE`, `ROWNW`, `ROWSE`, `ROWSW`). When I execute the stored procedure, data is fine. When I preview it through the datasource in asp.net, it shows up fine.  But it will NOT show up in the columns when the report runs.

I've recreated everything from scratch, and still not working.  All other fields, including one that is a decimal value, show up fine.  These last 4 values will not. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My stored procedure code:

```
SELECT     RR, State, SubDivision, MP, DOT, City, Street, ROWNE, ROWNW, ROWSE, ROWSW
FROM         dbo.Crossings
WHERE     (RR = @RR) AND (State = @State OR @State = 'ALL')
           AND (SubDivision = @Sub OR @Sub = 'ALL') 
           AND (ROWNE = 0 OR ROWNW = 0 OR ROWSE = 0 OR ROWSW = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

ROOKIE ERROR - 
I copy/pasted the method from another in the same area, and didn't change the stored procedure name in the report's method; both methods had similar fields, except for the 4 that didn't show through.  Lesson Learned.

Comment: Can you um accept your answer? Even then I'd like you to delete the question as this is quite useless